# Using the void ptr in the events structure for epoll

Tags: c, epoll

There is a [void pointer](http://linux.die.net/man/2/epoll_wait) in the epoll event structure. I am malloc-ing memory for this and using it elsewhere. Now when I want to take the FD off the epoll list, will this pointer be freed by itself? (A logical thought chain would be that the event structure is maintained internally, possibly by the kernel. So it would free the event strucutre and the memory allocated to the pointer too) Or would I have to free it explicitly?

P.S. I saw a piece of code that does not free the memory allocated to the pointer. I feel that it should be freed explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the pointer will not be freed by itself.  As far as the kernel is concerned, it's just an opaque value which it doesn't know how to deal with.  It doesn't know if it's a pointer into the stack, heap, data segment, or something else entirely.  So it couldn't possibly know that it should `free()` it.

The basic rule is, unless the documentation explicitly says otherwise, you are responsible for `free`ing any memory you `malloc`.  So, when you remove a file descriptor from an epoll list, you also need to `free` the corresponding pointer you `malloc`ed.

Comment: Further, there's no reason the pointer needs to point to memory obtained by `malloc`. The idea that "pointer" and "dynamically allocated memory" are synonymous is one of the most pervasive C newbie mistakes I see...

Comment: So, if I say, void *ptr = malloc(somesize); ptr is not going to point the malloc-ed memory? And where did I specifically state that pointer and dynamically allocated memory are synonymous? Don't make assumptions, please.

Comment: @Adam: That's what I figured too. It makes sense. The buggy code I saw made me wonder if there was any such mechanism which I might be unaware of.

Comment: If you assign the address of some malloc-obtained memory to the pointer, then yes it will point there. But just because you have a pointer variable does not mean it will necessarily be used to point to memory obtained by malloc.

Comment: Yes, of course. I did mention in my question that I'm malloc-ing memory for the pointer. I do realize that I can make it point to something else. But that is not what I'm doing. I intend to allocate memory to it on the heap.

Comment: I'm looking for a detailed explanation on how to handle memory management with epoll. The problem is that if you free the memory just after removing the watch from epoll instance, you may have events already in your queue but when processing the events, you can't learn whether the pointer now points to deallocated memory, can you?

Answer (score 2):

I have not used `epoll` before, but I think a very strong argument for that you have to free is is that the `epoll_data` is a union, so there is no way that any other code can be able to free whatever the pointer points to.

Comment: I didn't realize that it was a union. Thank god I didn't reference anything but the pointer! Thanks for pointing that out! (No pun intended)